# Randomly generate 4 or 5 digit Unique Codes in Subsequent Runs of the Script

Tags: python, perl, random

I have a requirement to Generate 10 4 or 5 Digit unique numbers. 
I can do that using Python/Perl, but the same script is going to run everyday to generate 10 random numbers. 
So I don't want them to repeat. If I generate them randomly then there is a probability that they will repeat.

Please suggest.

Comment: 5 digits numbers are guaranteed to repeat after at most 100,000 repetitions, so what do you want exactly?

Comment: @Thierry: So you're worried that a number may repeat after 27 years?

Comment: Hi Sujeet - I would choose one of those two languages first, try something, and if it doesn't work - post your code here.  Both Perl and Python have functions to create random names.  What's the downside of these numbers repeating?  Also, what's the greater context?

Comment: well, just create an array with the generated numbers. then look if the number you just generated is already into this array. If so, regenerate the number. If you are running the code several times, you will have to write the numbers into a txt file

Comment: To get 10 different numbers each day, first create a file that has a random permutation of all numbers from 1000 to 99999 (inclusive). (e.g. `say $fh $_ for shuffle(1000..99999);`. `shuffle` is provided by List::Util).  Then, when you need 10 numbers, use File::ReadBackwards to read the last 10 numbers of the file, then `truncate` the file where you left off.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you generate all possible 4 and 5 digit numbers, shuffle them (use [random.shuffle()](https://kite.com/python/docs/random.shuffle)) and then save to file. Then you could pick them every day by 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that your numbers will not repeat just generate a list of numbers and then shuffle it randomly

```
import numpy as np
numbers = np.arange(100000)  # Every number from 0 to 99999
np.random.shuffle(numbers)   # Now we shuffled everything
```

In this way you will not have any repetition since every number is unique. Then you can simply access the numbers in the `numbers` array from start to end

Answer (score 0):

There are only three ways to guarantee you'll get 10 numbers you've never gotten before:

- Randomly generate the numbers, but check if they've been generated before. If a number has been generated before, regenerate it, and repeat the check.

  With a small set of numbers, this will become slower with time.
- Encrypt an ascending stream of numbers.

  This solution requires the least storage (just the secret key and the number generated), but it's the most complicated option, and it breaks down if the secret key is compromised.
- Generate a non-repeating list of numbers in advance, then read from that list.

  This is the fastest approach, and the disk space used is negligible for a small set of numbers like yours.

All three approaches can easily be extended if you start running out of numbers.

The following is an implementation of the third approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

use File::ReadBackwards qw( );
use List::Util          qw( shuffle );

my $numbers_qfn = ...;

if (open(my $fh, '<', $numbers_qfn)) {
   die("Can't open numbers file \"$numbers_qfn\": $!\n") if !$!{ENOENT};

   open(my $fh, '>', $numbers_qfn)
      or die("Can't create numbers file \"$numbers_qfn\": $!\n");

   say $fh $_ for shuffle(1000..99999);
}

my $fh = File::ReadBackwards->new($numbers_qfn);
my @numbers;
while (@numbers < 10 && defined( my $line = $fh->readline )) {
   chomp($line);
   push @numbers, $line;
}

@numbers == 10
   or die("Insufficient numbers remaining\n");

truncate($fh->get_handle, $fh->tell)
   or die("Can't truncate numbers file \"$numbers_qfn\": $!\n");

say for @numbers;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you encrypt the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, ... then the encrypted outputs are guaranteed unique, thanks to the unique inputs.  Obviously, this will have to repeat after you have used all possible 5 digit numbers as input.

Look at [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) to ensure that your cypher output is a five digit number.

Five digits is 10,000 values, 14 bits.  Assuming security is not paramount, then a simple 14-bit four round Feistel cipher with a little cycle walking should be a good basis.  If security is important, then you will need something more like Hasty Pudding or AES-FFX, but inevitably more security takes longer to calculate.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# unique_random.pl : get N non-repeating random numbers from list
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Tie::File;
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

# get the number of values to print from command line
my $n = shift @ARGV;
$n = defined($n) ? int($n) : 10;
if ($n < 1 or $n > 100) { # sanity check
   $n = 10;
}

# persistent file of shuffled numbers tied to an array
my $file = 'random_numbers.txt';
tie my @numbers, 'Tie::File', $file or die "Can't tie $file";

# initialize the array if it's empty or not full enough
if ( scalar(@numbers) <= $n ) {
    @numbers = shuffle (1000 .. 99999); # all 4 and 5 digit numbers
}

# get the first $n numbers and delete them from the array
for ( 1 .. $n ) {
   say shift @numbers;
}
```

We could play Perl golf and make this more compact, but I went for legibility here.

Comment: Never use Tie::File. It's incredibly slower, and can easily use more memory than just  reading the entire file into memory (and it definitely will here). On top of that, you use it in the worse possible way. While shifting from the start of an array is fast, shifting from the start of a file is the worst thing you can do, and you do it 10 times! You should be popping instead.

Comment: With the help of File::Slurp, it would just have taken one extra line of code to avoid Tie::File. If you're worried about that, you can reclaim three lines by using `my $n = shift(@ARGV) // 10; $n = 10 if $n < 1 || $n > 100;`

Comment: Despite anyone's attempts to discredit `Tie::File`, it is a very useful module in its domain. The same applies to pretty much every CPAN module. Any calls of speed or memory inefficiency are no more than premature optimisation, and while a 30 second run time could be significantly better over a 3-second one, it is unusual for 30ms to be unacceptable unless the operation is a bottleneck. `Tie::File` is intended to offer programmed "text editing" facilities to Perl, and works very well as long as the files you use are of ordinary size that you would expect to alter with your regular editor.